# call python from php with 2 return values

Tags: php, python

I have a python script who is returning 2 values, humidity and temperature:

```
Temperature: 1.58050537109
Humidity: 89.2761230469
```

I call this srcipt from a PHP page but only one value is printed

```
<?php
echo exec("sudo python /home/pi/sht/sht31.py 2>&1");
?>
```

and only one humidity is printed. Could you please help me to print both value ?
Thank you

Comment: without sudo you cannot read I2C and used my script...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) with only command string, then it will return only the last line of output. To capture everything call it with second parameter to get all output:

```
exec('command', $output);
var_dump($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

now output is :

```
array(5) { [0]=> string(5) "False" [1]=> string(4) "True" [2]=> string(5) "False" [3]=> string(26) "Temperature: 1.56982421875" [4]=> string(23) "Humidity: 89.3859863281" }
```

with this code :

```
exec('sudo python /home/pi/sht/sht31.py' , $output);
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: Note that if the array already contains some elements, exec() will append to the end of the array. If you do not want the function to append elements, call unset() on the array before passing it to exec().