# How to get data from Python over to PHP

Tags: php, python

What are the possible methods to do this?

When I either open a page or click a button on my PHP website, it runs a python program that returns some data (maybe a string) back to PHP.

It seems people keep saying to use exec or shell exec but I tested this on WAMP, didn't work for me(maybe I did something wrong).

Is there a method I could do something like a API but not to access database but to just run a program?

EDIT: From advice on comments, I was able to get something.

```
exec('python get.py', $output);
var_dump($output);
```

using above, I got output.

```
C:\wamp64\www\ai\get.php:10:
array (size=0)
  empty
```

my python code is just a print statement that says hello world. do I need something for python side?

EDIT TWO: OMFG FINALLLUUYY GOT IT

```
$cmd = "C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe get.py";
exec($cmd, $output);

var_dump($output);
```

Comment: So you have a page on PHP that runs an external command (Python) and you would like to capture the Python's script output in your PHP, right?

Comment: yes, that is the hope. could it be that I'm using the wrong pathing? here is what I'm using. "python get.py". running windows with php and py files on same folder using WAMP

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753391/call-python-from-php-with-2-return-values